# Удаление элемента javascript

Tags: javascript

Имею добавление полей в форме, по отправке (submit) происходит валидация(тут описана не будет смоделируем данную ситуацию)

```
function val() {
var el = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.setAttribute("name", "err-mess");
    newdiv.innerHTML = "Тупо текст";
    el[i].parentNode.insertBefore(newdiv, el[i]);
    return false;
}}
```

Как мне удалить все Div Блоки (добавленые) кроме последнего добавленного, опять же по нажатию на кнопку submit

Answer (score 3):

Каждому добавленному блоку можно добавить класс `"added"`.

```
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.className = newdiv.className + " added";
```

После отправки формы:

```
removeElementsByClass('added');

function removeElementsByClass(className){
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    while(elements.length > 0){
        elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
    }
}
```

Если воспользоваться jQuery:
После отправки формы:

```
$('.added').each(function(){
    $(this).remove();
})
```